# How to make printf in bash script with a variable which comes from txt text with NEW LINES

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to read a txt file which has new lines, for example this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Hi, this is a txt file that I will make a printf
# and I will execute later

VARIABLE_A=%s
VARIABLE_B=%s
VARIABLE_C=%s
```

so, this is my file `txt_script.sh`

and what I'm trying to do, is:

1. Making my own bash script.
2. Read `txt_script.sh` in a variable as text.
3. Use printf to change those `%s`
4. Write it in a new file.

My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

create_script=`cat model_files/txt_script.sh`

create_script=`printf "$create_script" $1 $2 $3`

echo -e $create_script > model_files/create_imagenet_generated.sh
```

but my final txt file gets this format:

(If I execute `./my_bash_script.sh aAa bBb cCc`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh # Hi, this is a txt file that I will make a printf # and I will execute later VARIABLE_A=aAa VARIABLE_B=bBb VARIABLE_C=cCc
```

How can I make it readable to be able to execute as bash script? like that, is everything a comment.

Thank you in advance.

Rafael.

Comment: quote your `echo` to keep the format: `echo -e "$create_script"`

Comment: oh god.. thank you. I'm really new learning bash since I didn't study computer science... could you convert your comment in answer? I will validate it as Correct. Thank you!

Comment: No problem : ) I just marked it as duplicate to a "canonical" answer for this situation (because it is quite a common mistake). Happy programming!

Comment: You can also use: `printf "$create_script\n" aAa bBb cCc > model_files/create_imagenet_generated.sh` and skip the `echo` part.

Comment: I've gone across 8 or 9 posts and didn't find it... sorry! thank you very much.